# Convert money value to cents

Tags: javascript, math, currency, currency-formatting, money-format

I want to get string input for money value and I need integer (cents) to store it. But I need to present it back to the user on UI which mean that I need to get that value back from integer.

The problem is 455.000 (455 x 1000) but I get 455. So I made something terribly wrong in this calculation.

```js
const toCent = amount => {
  const str = amount.toString().replace(',', '.')
  const [int] = str.split('.')
  return Number(amount.toFixed(2).replace('.', '').padEnd(int.length === 1 ? 3 : 4, '0'))
}
console.log(toCent(parseFloat('45.99')));
console.log(toCent(parseFloat('455.000')));
console.log((Math.round((toCent(parseFloat('45.99')) / 100 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100).toString());
console.log((Math.round((toCent(parseFloat('455.000')) / 100 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100).toString());
```

Comment: it's depending on country, in anglo saxon countries the decimal point is a point, on latin countries it is a comma, and the point is used to separate the thousands

Comment: I am not sure I use this in react native. @MisterJojo I am thinkng if I just remove from string 455.000 dots and commas this is number of cents then right? 
In Intl later I can use it `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('sr-RS', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format('455000'));
` and get `"455.000,00 €"` or in USD `"455.000,00 US$"` I don't know if thi is universal.

Comment: The question is a little unclear about the input/output: "get string input for money value".  The input is a string representing a quantity of US dollars?  It may contain commas and a decimal point?  I understand we want it saved as an integer of US $0.01.  Do we then want it back as a string with commas?  US dollar symbol?

Comment: It's text input field and user can enter number for price: 1000, 1500, 1500.00, 1500,00 he just enter price for his product. And he can select currency like EUR, USD, CHF and I need to get cents as in db I need to keep this values as integers. And I want later to be able to get that price back in value he entered. But seems like simple math of converting to cents becoming nightmare.

Comment: I think it seems that way because you’re not passing what you’re supposed to be passing to `toCent` because you’re passing through `parseFloat`, which converts ‘455.000’ to 455.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will work with input of the form D[sC] where D is dollars with optional thousands separators, s is the dollars-cents separator, and C is *two-digit* (zero-padded) cents.

```js
const toCent = amount => {
  const str = amount.replace(',', '.')
  return str.length < 3 || str[str.length - 3] == '.' ? Number(str.replace('.', '')) : Number(str.replace('.', ''))*100
}
console.log(toCent('45.99'));
console.log(toCent('455.000'));
console.log(toCent('45.99')/100);
console.log(toCent('455.000')/100);
```